# Continuity and sequences , with only existence of one sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

In a true/false exercise, I saw the following proposition: if there is ($x_n$) which converges to x and such that f($x_n$) converges to f(x) when n tends towards infinity then f is continuous in x. I think this proposition is false since we have the existence of a single sequence and not the respected property for any sequence but I can't find a counter-example. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = 0$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$. Of course $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$, but for the constant sequence $x_n = 0$, you have $f(x_n)=1$ which converges to $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Thank you. I considered also the following example : f(x) = 1 (x $\in \mathbb{Q} $) ; f(x) = 0 (x $\notin \mathbb{Q} $)

Comment: @chloe2107 Yes this is correct ! actually every non-continuous function can give a counterexample, since the constant sequence equal to $x$ (where $x$ is a discontinuity point) will work.